# How to scrape a flash based site?

Tags: c#, flash, web-scraping, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

We are using *Html Agility Pack* to scrape data for HTML-based site; is there any DLL like *Html Agility Pack* to scrape flash-based site?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Flash sites are unscrapable.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the site you are trying to scrap. There are two types of sites in this regard:

- If the site has the data inside the swf file, then you'll have to decompile the swf file, and read the data inside. with enough work you can probably do it programmatically. However if this is the case, it might be easier to just gather the data manually, since it's probably isn't going to change much.
- If most cases however, especially with sites that have a lot of data, the flash file is actually contacting an external API. In that case you can simply ignore the flash altogether and get to the API directly. If your not sure, just activate Firebug's net panel, and start browsing. If it's using an external api it should become obvious. 
   
  Once you find that API, you could probably reverse engineer how to manipulate it to give you whatever data you need.

Also note that if it's a big enough site, there are probably non-flash ways to get to the same data:

- It might have a mobile site (with no flash) - try accessing the site with an iPhone user-agent.
- It might have a site for crawlers (like googlebot) - try accessing the site with a googlebot user-agent.

EDIT:
if your talking about crawling (crawling means getting data from any random site) rather then scraping (Getting structured data from a specific site), then there's not much you can do, even googlebot isn't scrapping flash content. Mostly because unlike HTML, flash doesn't have a standardized syntax that you can immediately tell what is text, what is a link etc...

Answer (score 1):

You won't have much luck with the HTML Agility Pack.  One method would be to use something like [FiddlerCore](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Core/) to proxy HTTP requests to/from a Flash site.  You would start the FiddlerCore proxy, then use something like the C# WebBrowser to go to the URL you want to scrape.  As the page loads, all those HTTP requests will get proxied and you can inspect their contents. However, you wouldn't get most text since that's often static within the Flash.  Instead, you'd get mostly larger content (videos, audio, and maybe images) that are usually stored separately.  This will be slowed compared to more traditional scraping/crawling because you'll actually have to execute/run the page in the browser.

If you're familiar with all of those YouTube Downloader type of extensions, they work on this same principal except that they intercept HTTP requests directly from FireFox (for example) rather than a separate proxy.

I believe that Google and some of the big search engines have a special arrangement with Adobe/Flash and are provided with some software that lets their search engine crawlers see more of the text and things that Google relies on.  Same goes for PDF content.  I don't know if any of this software is publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

Scraping Flash content would be quite involved, and the reliability of any component that claims to do so is questionable at best. However, if you wish to "crawl" or follow hyperlinks in a Flash animation on some web page, you might have some luck with [Infant](http://www.infant-ir.info/). Infant is a free Java library for web crawling, and offers limited / best-effort Flash content hyperlink following abilities. Infant is not open source, but is free for personal and commercial use. No registration required!

Comment: Infant can be used but I think they were looking for a c# implementation!

Answer (score -1):

How about capturing the whole page as an image and running an [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) on the page to read the data